# Mod rewrite without .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts

Let's suppose I have a website named

```
foo.com
```

I can access `foo.com` and it runs the `index.php` found in the root folder. My question is: how should I edit the vhost file to enable rewrite mod without enabling htaccess?

My goal is to be able to write

```
http://foo.com/bar/loremipsum/dolor
```

into my browser address bar and to run index.php regardless of the number of / characters in the url. My index.php would handle the parameters separated by /

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myproject.com
        ServerAlias www.myproject.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /opt/apps/myproject

        <Directory /opt/apps/myproject>
            # disable htaccess
            AllowOverride None

            # route everything to index.php
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: The problem, as the accepted answer suggests is that this host did not contain the line which turns the rewrite engine on. This line is present in the answer. Which solves the problem.

Comment: I am open to criticism. I would gladly read why my question is bad/unhelpful

Comment: There is nothing you `need` to edit in vhost file. If the mod_rewrite module is enabled, then you just add your rules in the specific vhost in a `Directory ` directive. If it's not enable the module then add the rules as mentioned.

Comment: I see. So, if it is enabled, things like this RewriteRule ^(.*)$              index.php [QSA,L] should work in a Directory tag?

Comment: That's correct, there is nothing special you need to do.

Comment: and Apache has to be restarted, right?

Comment: That is correct. I could have just made an answer. but whatever. :)

Comment: I will certainly accept the answer if it solves the problem. I am by far not an apache guru, so my question might be naive. This makes down-votes potentially valid. I would gladly sacrifice some karma to solve the problem and help future visitors sharing my confusion

Comment: Well Jon, pretty much provided an answer on pretty much what I was saying. So it's fine.

Comment: I ran a2enmod rewrite, restarted the server, the virtual host contains the content described by John Lin, but unfortunately the site does not work, index.php is not reached

Comment: run `apache2ctl -M | grep rewrite` and say what the output is.

Comment: It shows you the load modules and looks for rewrite.

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
rewrite_module (shared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disallow the use of htaccess, you need this directive in a `<Directory>` container for your document root, then you can just place mod_rewrite rules in the same container:

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs/">
    # disable htaccess
    AllowOverride None

    # route everything to index.php
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

assuming that "/var/www/htdocs" is you document root.

To ensure mod_rewrite is loaded, check the httpd.conf file for a `LoadModule` line that contains mod_rewrite, and make sure it's uncommented. You'll need to restart your server anytime you make changes to the vhost config.

Short explanation:

The lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

are conditions to check that the request is **not** an existing file (`-f`) or an existing directory (`-d`). These conditions serve 2 main purposes:

1. It prevents the rewrite engine from looping, so that `index.php` won't also get rewritten. Since `index.php` is an existing file, the conditions stop the rewrite engine.
2. It allows resources and assets like images or scripts from being rewritten.

If you want **everything** routed to `index.php` no matter what (including images or anything else), then you can change the 2 conditions to simply:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
```

so that everything gets rewritten except `index.php`.

Comment: I am searching for httpd.conf. I hope I can find it easily

Comment: Invalid command RewriteCond. I have to set the LoadModule, I guess.

Comment: I ran a2enmod rewrite, restarted the server, but http://foo.com/bar is not running index.php

Comment: @LajosArpad does `/bar` exist as a directory?

Comment: No, it does not exist in the root. It exists in other places. But I would like to run index.php even if a bar directory does not exist. For instance foo.com/bar/lorem/ipsum should run index.php, which will parse the parameters, such that param0 = bar, param1 = lorem param2 = ipsum. Basically, I would like to run index.php regardless of the url.

Comment: All this works locally, but there I allow .htaccess. However, I am a noob in apache and in regular expressions.

Comment: I believe this can be achieved by a combo of rewrite conditions and rewrite rules, I just do not know how to write it. I have been reading about this for hours. However, as always, when someone is not proficient in an area, the results pour in very slowly. I am sorry for being a noob, I plan to learn about these aspects so in the future I will be able to give something back to the community for the favor I receive here.

Comment: @LajosArpad Don't know why it's not working. [It works perfectly fine in my vhost config](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmFaX.png). Anything I request routes to the root's index.php

Comment: I believe you, it is probably something to do with my configuration. I have edited my question and added vhost details. Can you take a look? Thank you again and sorry for the repeated bothering. I up-vote your answer anyway due to your attempt to try to help.

Comment: @LajosArpad ok, is my bad, forgot to turn on the rewrite engine. In my vhost I had it turned on in another `<Directory>` container

Comment: Jon, this was the missing puzzle. I accept the solution as it is, since it solved the problem. Outside the question, if you would describe what these lines do, then I would understand the solution as well:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Anyway, thank you very much for the solution. I have utmost respect for your nice attitude and the will to help. Well done, friend, kudos to you!

Comment: Jon, the explanation is understandable, it allows me to understand what happens under the hood. Thank you very much.